# Image missing in word application using C#

Tags: c#, image, ms-word

I am creating a Word document (say: child.doc) from another word document (say: base.doc) using C#.

There is an image in base.doc which is placed in the header.  I am copying the contents from base.doc and pasting the contents into child.doc using C#.

After this process I am saving the child.doc through code.  If I open the saved document (ie:child.doc) manually (not through the code) the image in the header part is missing.  What am I doing wrong?

I am using the following code:

```
  string path = "base.doc"; // path of base document
  object format = (object)Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;
  object formatPdf = (object)Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
  object readOnly = true;
  object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
  Word._Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
  object file = @path;
  object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
  wordApp.Visible = false;
  wordApp.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
  Word._Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(
        ref file, ref nullobj, ref readOnly,
        ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
        ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
        ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

  doc.Activate();

  Word.Range docRange = doc.Content;

  // After these codes i do some replacement in the conten like as follows

  docRange.Find.Text = "Some text to replace";
  docRange.Find.Replacement.Text = "Replacement text";
  docRange.Find.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

  docRange.Find.Forward = true;
  object rangeStart = docRange.Start;
  object rangeEnd = docRange.End;
  Word.Range rng = doc.Range(ref rangeStart, ref rangeEnd);
  rng.Font.Name = "Arial";

  Word._Document inewDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,    ref nullobj);
  rng.Copy();
  inewDoc.Application.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
  inewDoc.SaveAs(ref tempPath, ref format, ref nullobj,
                           ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                           ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                           true, ref nullobj,
                           ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                           ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);


  doc.Close(ref saveChanges, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
  doc = null;
  inewDoc.Close(ref saveChanges, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
  inewDoc = null;
  wordApp.Quit(ref saveChanges, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
  wordApp = null;
```

Comment: If the document is created and downloaded in same machine(ie:PC) there is no problem.If we created in one machine ( i use server machine) and download it to some other machine (i use My PC) the problem is exist.This is the real problem that i have..

Comment: I found the solution.Actually the problem is with my image format. I am used .tif format it is not working with word appliction.So i changed .tif format to .png format.Now it is working fine.

Comment: if you've solved your question, you should post your comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.Actually the problem is with my image format. I am used .tif format it is not working with word appliction.So i changed .tif format to .png format.Now it is working fine. –